# Cookie doesn't store information in php?

Tags: php, cookies

Why Cookies doesn't store information in php ?

even in this simple code ..

```
<?
   setcookie("test","Cookies teso");
   echo "My cookie value: ".$_COOKIE["test"];
?>
```

Comment: off topic: Note, you should use long-version PHP tags -- ie `<?php` instead of `<?`. Current versions of PHP default to not allow the shorter version, so as it is, your code may not work at all on some PHP servers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They will be available on the next page load. From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that
>   the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully
>   set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie
>   expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to
>   debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling
>   print_r($_COOKIE);.

Note that you need to set the cookies before any other script output is done:

> Like other headers, cookies must be sent ***before*** any output from your
>   script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place
>   calls to this function prior to any output, including  and
>    tags as well as any whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

page needs to be refreshed.

`$_COOKIE` has the cookies from your browser from the start of the execution of the script.  `setcookie()` sets the information in the browser, but that info isn't yet in the `$_COOKIE` array.  it will be at the next page load, though